# Django - How to set the empty_value choice as the last choice instead of the first in a ModelChoiceField?

Tags: django

I have a ModelChoiceField that works the way I want it to with the exception of the empty_value choice appearing first instead of last.

Is there a way to set it to show up last?  Perhaps by reversing all of the choices before they're displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a bit of sub classing to do this. All the relevant code is in [`django.forms.models`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.4/django/forms/models.py)

First, You'll need to subclass `ModelChoiceIterator` to return the empty label after the choices. Then subclass `ModelChoiceField` To use your custom interator. Finally, use your custom model choice field in your form.